# In what order SQL statement execute if Select statement has CONCAT function on some columns?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have been trying to understand the code that is the part of the BigQuery course on Coursera. The query looks like this

```
   SELECT 
   CONCAT(fullVisitorId, CAST(visitID AS STRING)) AS unique_session_id,
   sessionQualityDim,
   SUM(productRevenue) AS transactions_revenue

   FROM
   transaction_table
   WHERE sessionQualityDim > 60
   GROUP BY unique_session_id, sessionQualityDim
```

My question is how would the order of the SQL statement would execute. Mainly when the GROUP BY is done on unique_session_id (which is the CONCAT between two columns), how would 'GROUP BY' knows about the calculated CONCAT results(unique_session_id). From my knowledge the SELECT statement would run in the last. But in this case it seems like first field is calculated using CONCAT and then group by is using that for grouping. Can someone give more insights on this ?

Comment: Generally `GROUP BY` is one of the last steps to run (HAVING and some other vendor specific clauses follow). This is true on every RDBMS under the sun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the SQL standard, the `GROUP BY` is parsed *before* the `SELECT`.

However, this is not a hard-and-fast rule among databases.  What BigQuery is doing is determining the column aliases from the `SELECT`.  It then allows these aliases in the `GROUP BY`.  Other databases do this as well -- Postgres and all its derived databases for example.

Do not confuse the parsing of the query with the execution, though.  The execution is through some very complicated parallel directed acyclic graph.  What is happening here is simply that the BigQuery parser is (conveniently) allowing users to use table aliases in `GROUP BY`.